# SSRS Parameter for "pay period"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Is there a way, in SSRS, to have a parameter called "Pay Period" that allows only selection of a specific date range? For example, only allowing 09/19/2016 through 09/25/2016, and not allowing 09/20/2016 through 09/26/2016. Any Monday - Sunday combination is fine, but otherwise, no go.

I was thinking of a drop-down list that offered these ranges (as opposed to two different parameters) but am unsure of how to make that work.

Comment: I think you could have two parameters to let users select the date range but have two additional parameters set to be hidden in order to validate and pass the date range to your query.

Comment: I think I've done that before as well. Just thought it'd be nice if you could do one parameter with both dates, but wasn't sure if it was possible.

Comment: It is possible, but you will have to create a query that returns each range and use it to populate the parameter, and in the query you are passing the parameter you need to process the value to convert it in two SQL parameters with start date and end date.

Comment: The only way you could do this in the one parameter would be to have a data driven parameter with values like `09/19/2016 - 09/25/2016` which you then handle in your dataset accordingly.

Comment: If you have specific date definitions for your business, i.e. pay periods, then you should save these to a table and use them from there. So you'd have a table with one record per pay period containing a start date and an end date and a label. You select from this table to populate your drop down. You join to this table in your report query and filter on it. This saves people having to remember specific dates (and possibly messing them up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a single parameter for the start date and calculate the end date as 6 days past this (if you need it).

For the parameter, I would create a field for the label while using the single start date field for the data.

**Parameter Query:**

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE = '01/01/2016' 
DECLARE @END_DATE  DATE  = '10/31/2016'

;WITH GETDATES AS  
    (  
        SELECT @START_DATE AS THEDATE
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, THEDATE) FROM GETDATES  
        WHERE THEDATE < @END_DATE  
)

SELECT THEDATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), THEDATE, 101) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(D, 6, THEDATE), 101) AS PAYPERIOD
FROM GETDATES 
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, THEDATE) = 2
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

This would let the user see the date range but only pass the starting date to the report to use as needed.

```
DATE        PAYPERIOD

2016-01-04  01/04/2016 - 01/10/2016

2016-01-11  01/11/2016 - 01/17/2016 

2016-01-18  01/18/2016 - 01/24/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2 parameters for a date range all the time. You would have to make sure your query account for these parameters. I usually use @StartDate and @EndDate

```
WHERE <columnName> BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

As long as you declare the two parameters in you query you should be ok. When you use the Date/Time data type in the parameter then you will get a nice date picker to use. This at least works for me every time.

Comment: Yes, I've done basic start and end dates before as well. I'm trying to determine if it can be done by only accepting Monday through Sunday combinations, possibly via something other than a pair of date parameters.